# Передача данных между страницами ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Здравствуйте. Появилась проблема с передачей данных между двумя страницами. На первой у меня GridView с помещённой в него из бд oracle таблицей. А на второй форма для добавления новой строки. И вот мне нужно на второй веб форме открыть коннект в переменную типа Oraclecommand записать запрос на insert и по нажатию кнопки "Ок" передать переменную с запросом на первую веб форму. Дальше соответственно перехватить эти данные и выполнить, ну либо выполнить их уже удалённо со второй веб формы. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать. Я знаю что во viewstate можно сохранить любого рода переменную например в моём случае. Но как выполнить этот запрос или перехватить эту переменную на первой странице? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: ViewState одной страницы не будет валидным для другой. В вашем случае, вы можете хранить данные в сесии/кукисах, или в id-пользователя (который передавать в get или post-параметрах).

Comment: А вы не могли бы привести пример как мне можно передать например строку из текстбокса и засунуть её в переменную на первой странице.                       Спасибо заранее.